# not detecting wireless card in ubuntu 13.04 lenovo g580 laptop

Tags: 13.04, wireless, lenovo

Earlier wifi was not working in ubuntu 13.04 lenovo g580 laptop then i installed some packages reboot my system.then no wifi setting s were their in all settings/network.earlier it was showing disconnected but now even this is not showing. 
this are my network properties

```
av@av-Lenovo-G580:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:88:e3:8a:95:06  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:130652 errors:0 dropped:37 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8867 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19859927 (19.8 MB)  TX bytes:1388221 (1.3 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:75625 (75.6 KB)  TX bytes:75625 (75.6 KB)

av@av-Lenovo-G580:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for av: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for av: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:88:e3:8a:95:06
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 memory:90500000-9053ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90400000-90403fff
```

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
sudo modprobe brcmsmac
```

Detach the ethernet. Is your wireless working now? If not, check the log for clues:

```
dmesg | grep -e wl -e brcm
```